# Can I set a UITextField to trigger the action of a UIBarButtonItem when Return is pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitextfield, uibarbuttonitem

I've completed the tutorial project that is part of the Apple Dev Center's "[Start Developing iOS Apps Today](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/ThirdTutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH10-SW1)" guide. The project builds a simple 2-view To-Do List app. The main view is a list of to-do items, and the second view uses a text field to add a new to-do item.  The views are linked by a navigation controller.

Currently, the user adds an item by entering it in the text field and pressing the "Done" UIBarButtonItem. I'd like to set it up so pressing the Return key in the text field triggers the same action as pressing "Done".

I've searched on StackOverflow and elsewhere and I've looked at the relevant Apple docs, and I can't figure out how to make what seems like a simple connection. So I'm wondering if the fact that the Done button is a navigation control which triggers a Segue and an UnwindToList  means I can't easily link it to the Return key.

Based on the answers I've found here, I've set the ViewController up to be the text field's delegate:

(in the .h file)

```
@interface XYZAddToDoItemViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

(in the .m file)

```
self.textField.delegate = self;
```

And I've added the function

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

}
```

But I can't figure out how to use that function to trigger the Done button pressed event. The view controller has a PrepareForSegue method which checks the text field and saves the data in it, so presumably I have to call that method and then initiate the segue, but I can't figure out how to do that manually, since the Navigation Controller normally handles it.

Comment: Simply call the `IBAction` method setup for the "Done" button from your `textFieldShouldReturn:` method.

Comment: I think the issue is that the navigation controller provides the Done button and handles the action so there's no code per se.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this right, the problem you have is that the 'Done' button is a UIBarButton item in a Navigation bar that's handled by a UINavigationController, so you don't have any code that does the dismissal and therefore are stuck as to how to tie the return event from the textfield (which you correctly identified the method for). Is that right?

If so... You need to add a method to manually do what the 'Done' button does automatically.
This will depend on how the original presentation happened. 
One way is to look into the unwind segue option.
However in the short term, add this and call it from the textFieldShouldReturn method...

```
- (void)manualDoneAction {
   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Post your results and if it didn't help I'll see what else might work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply -- your understanding of the situation is correct, and I will give your suggestion a try and report back :-)